# compute variable after datalines

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset (fictional data).

```
DATA test;
    INPUT name $ age height weight;
    DATALINES;
Peter 20 1.70 80
Hans 30 1.72 75
Tina 25 1.67 65
Luisa 10 1.20 50
;
RUN;
```

How can I compute a new variable "bmi" (weight / height^2) directly after the end of the DATALINE-command? Unfortunately in my SAS-book all the examples are with DATA ... INFILE= instead of using DATALINES.

```
PROC PRINT 
    DATA = test;
    TITLE 'Fictional Data';
RUN;
```

Comment: The spurious `RUN;` statement in your first block of code is probably what is confusing you.  Since it comes after the data step it is just generating an empty step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Datalines` appears at the end of the `data` step.  Your computation statements should be placed before `datalines`, after the `input`

```
INPUT name $ age height weight;
bmi = weight / height**2;
DATALINES;
…
```